# Approving a reject

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

Using the word "approve" in the review section is rather ambiguous.

Person A edited my post. Then, person B rejected the edit. Now is my turn to accept or reject. I have only one choice of clicking the "approve".

I have no idea in interpreting the meaning of the word "approve". To approve it means (1) the edit itself; or (2) the rejection to the edit?

Comment: Unless the Edit is being made to your own post, you would review the Edit without knowing what someone else had decided.  Reject means reject the Edit.  As the author of the post you can immediately accept the Edit if you wish.

Comment: @hardmath That is not what I meant. I received a message from the help center saying that someone has edited my post and at the same time someone is disproving the edit. Both the original version and the edited version made were displayed side by side. I was asked to click the only “approve” button. By clicking it, am I approving the edit? Or approving the reject? That is the ambiguous part!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first of your two options (in the post).

"Approve" means that you approve the proposal to edit the post.

As post owner you can override the reviewers decision. If you "approve" the original proposal will be applied even if reviewers rejected it.

Conversely if the reviewers approved it initially you could still reject it. 
In that case there should  be no ambiguity though, as you reject both the edit and the review.

Think of it like reviewing the suggestion as if there were no reviews before.

For details with screenshots and alike see this [answer from an official source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028) on the main meta.

Comment: Just to clarify the matter. Suggestion = reject the edit made. Approve = agree with the suggestion. So, clicking the “approve” button means I agree with the suggestion and therefore such edit should not been made. Is that correct? What happens if I still want to accept the edited, what action should I make?

Comment: No. "Aprove" means that you agree with the original edit (that was suggested). I wrote edit-suggestion as there is no edit yet, only a suggestion. Once you approve the suggestion it will become an edit.

Comment: Thanx for the clarification

Comment: The meaning of the "approve" button is now clear. I still have one more question:- What should I do if I agree with the rejection of that edit? There is no other option button for me to click!

Comment: In that case there is nothing to do. Thus you do nothing specific. Just keep browsing the site or do whatever else you wish to do. :-) If you are worried how to leave the subpage. Just click say "Questions".